# Rail 4: implementation of shoryuken background process gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, backgroundworker, background-process

Im just trying to implement a background process (for the first time) and I was looking for a cheap solution and I found this gem [shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken), but there is not enough material about its setup, do you know a tutorial or blog post that shows shoryuken in action? any material you could give me would be good I did deep research in google but could not find anythign useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote this blog post on how I used Shoryuken with Rails. In the post, I use it to queue fetching and saving of Instagram posts:

http://alex.aspria.net/using-shoryuken-amazon-sqs-with-rails.html

Comment: Thanks Im gonna read it, by the way, the blog layout is pretty cool! =)

Comment: Link seems to be broken :( . Can you post a step-by-step to SO instead of linking externally?

Comment: @dhulihan sorry about that, was in the process of moving my domain registrar, should be ok now